# Accessing related tables with [ForeignKey] without actually having a foreign key in the DB, while using EF Core

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

I'm reverse-engineering a third-party database that I can't change. There are no foreign keys, but FK relationship have been enforced by the application that was using it, so the data is OK.

I've run scaffolding of tables via `Scaffold-DbContext` and got classes created. Now due to lack of FKs I have a problem. Here are simplified version of generated classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int EmployeeType {get; set; }
    // other fields
}

public class EmployeeType
{
     public int EmployeeType { get; set; } // this is the key in this table
     // other fields
}
```

So an Employee has a type assigned to it, where types are stored in a lookup table. And now I'd like to query employee together with their type. So I'm trying:

```
public class Person
{
    public int EmployeeType {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(EmployeeType))]
    public EmployeeType EmployeeTypeReference { get; set; }

    // other fields
}

var people = dbContext.Person
        .Include(p => p.EmployeeTypeReference)
        .Where(p => p.EmployeeType != null)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
var k = people.Select(c => new { c.EmployeeType, c.EmployeeTypeReference}).ToList();
```

And then I see this:

[image]

I.e. the related object is not retrieved.

I've also tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne<EmployType>(e => e.EmployeeTypeReference)
                      .WithMany(t => t.People);
}
```

But the result is the same.

Anything else I can try doing to get the related object through with `.Include`?

Comment: I would do my best to update the database and add the FK. What you are trying to achieve is so unsecure if possible at all.

Comment: @Siavash I only have read-only access to the DB. Can't change it, as it is used by other application. Why unsecure?

Comment: This should work. Make sure the actual query does not fall into ignored includes category (check the executed SQL command, it should contain join of `Person` and `EmployeeType` tables).

Comment: @IvanStoev checked the executed sql, both cases (using `[ForeignKey]` and `entity.HasOne<EmployType>(e => e.EmployeeTypeReference).WithMany(t => t.People);`) have return a simple `select * from person` without any joins

Comment: It should work though. There must be something wrong in the real mapping / usage. Can you provide a minimal repro? (btw, current sample does not event compile - `EmployeeType` class cannot have `EmployeeType` property). Try reproducing in clean project with just two entities with only PK and relationships mappings.

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah, that's a typo, attempting to cut down the stuff around it.

Comment: @IvanStoev fixed it.I was using `.Include` from EF6, not from EF Core. See my answer. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with the user as per usual. However some people might be caught out by this as well, so I'll spell it out.

Issue was with `.Include()`. I was using EF6 version of from namespace `System.Data.Entity`. But I needed EF Core version that came from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

That was brought by dual-running EF6 (because dependencies) and EF Core in the same project.